# How to update specific object in array NodeJS, MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating Reservation System where now i need to update specific object which is inside an Array.

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5f3fdcf463153719845e32e9"
   },
   "do_kogo":"Doctor",
   "Startdate":"8/21/2020, 1:00:00 AM",
   "EndDate":"8/21/2020, 2:00:00 AM",
   "StartdateFormatPL":"21.08.2020, 01:00:00",
   "EndDateFormatPL":"21.08.2020, 02:00:00",
   "godziny":[
      {
         "id":"rbprEs",
         "hour":"21.08.2020, 01:00:00",
         "isBooked":false,
         "isConfirmed":false
      },
      {
         "id":"lT8WkM",
         "hour":"21.08.2020, 01:05:00",
         "isBooked":false,
         "isConfirmed":false
      },
      {
         "id":"n4PJ3V",
         "hour":"21.08.2020, 01:10:00",
         "isBooked":false,
         "isConfirmed":false
      },
      {
         "id":"aHM-Gn",
         "hour":"21.08.2020, 01:15:00",
         "isBooked":false,
         "isConfirmed":false
      },
      {
         "id":"-EFbRV",
         "hour":"21.08.2020, 01:20:00",
         "isBooked":false,
         "isConfirmed":false
      },
      {
         "id":"X64wkx",
         "hour":"21.08.2020, 01:25:00",
         "isBooked":false,
         "isConfirmed":false
      },
      {
         "id":"eXv451",
         "hour":"21.08.2020, 01:30:00",
         "isBooked":false,
         "isConfirmed":false
      },
      {
         "id":"xxni5q",
         "hour":"21.08.2020, 01:35:00",
         "isBooked":false,
         "isConfirmed":false
      },
      {
         "id":"sTkns7",
         "hour":"21.08.2020, 01:40:00",
         "isBooked":false,
         "isConfirmed":false
      },
      {
         "id":"MaffJR",
         "hour":"21.08.2020, 01:45:00",
         "isBooked":false,
         "isConfirmed":false
      },
      {
         "id":"8DFBra",
         "hour":"21.08.2020, 01:50:00",
         "isBooked":false,
         "isConfirmed":false
      },
      {
         "id":"3Jb5yE",
         "hour":"21.08.2020, 01:55:00",
         "isBooked":false,
         "isConfirmed":false
      }
   ],
   "__v":{
      "$numberInt":"0"
   }
}
```

and what i need is to find main object by its `id:5f3fdcf463153719845e32e9` and then  from `godziny[]` by its id like "rbprEs". After that i need to change `isBooked` value from false to True or the other way.

i need to get:

```
{
             "id":"rbprEs",
             "hour":"21.08.2020, 01:00:00",
             "isBooked":true,
             "isConfirmed":false
          },
```

I was trying code below but it is not working properly.

```
    router
.post("/upgrade/:id/:id2", (req, res) => {
  ReservationHours.findOneAndUpdate(
    { 
      // convert id to object id if not using (mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id))
      _id: req.params.id, 
      godziny: {
          $elemMatch: {
              id: req.params.id2,
              isBooked: false
          }
      }
    },
    // use positional operator $ to update in specific object
    { $set: { "godziny.$.isBooked": true } }
  )
  .then(ReservationHours =>
      ReservationHours.save().then(() => res.json({ success: true }))
  )
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
});
```

But how can i get  and update parameter which is so nested ?

Also code in React of that post:

```
export const updateReservationHours = (id, id2) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    axios.post(`/reservationshours/${id}/${id2}`, tokenConfig(getState)).then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_RESERVATION_HOURS,
        payload: (id, id2)
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html),

```
ReservationHours.findOneAndUpdate(
  { 
    // convert id to object id if not using (mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id))
    _id: req.params.id, 
    godziny: {
        $elemMatch: {
            // you can set it dynamic by using (req.params.godziny)
            // if its multiple and array then use id: { $in: req.params.godziny }
            id: "rbprEs", 
            isBooked: false
        }
    }
  },
  // use positional operator $ to update in specific object
  { $set: { "godziny.$.isBooked": true } },
  // get updated original document
  { projection: { "godziny.$": 1 } } 
)
.then(ReservationHours =>
    ReservationHours.save().then(() => res.json({ success: true }))
)
.catch(err => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
```

Comment: what if the second id "rbprEs" is also send as req.param ?

Comment: you mean multiple ids? or dynamic ids you can set it check the updated comment

Comment: i mean i am sending two params. first identify the main object. and then second id identify specific object inside an array which is inside main object.

Comment: yes that what it is in my answer, i am not getting you if i am wrong, can you give proper understanding with example and code.

Comment: Editted main post. if you have more questions i will update that.

Comment: i have already commented, convert `req.params.id` to object id using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)` if its not.